# Hypothesis Testing of Binned Data

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics

I am currently trying to run a linear model on the mean difference between males and females for a trait (the response variable) over time (binned).

I have binned the following data by year, but am wondering how I can assess significance of the resulting regression because the data are binned and there are few bins.

```
Data$cuts <- as.numeric(cut(Data$year, breaks = c(0,1910, 1950, 2000, 2016), labels = FALSE))
```

I then subset the data by sex

```
DataM <- Data[Data$sex=="M",]
DataF <- Data[Data$sex=="F",]
```

Here I run a loop to generate the mean difference between males and females at each point.

```
mean.df <- as.data.frame(c())

for (i in 1:4) {
  Mcuts <- DataM[which(DataM$cuts==i),]
  Fcuts <- DataF[which(DataF$cuts==i),]
  Mmean <- mean(Mcuts$trait, na.rm = TRUE)
  Fmean <- mean(Fcuts$trait, na.rm = TRUE)
  mean.df[i, "bin"] <- paste(i)
  mean.df[i, "mean_dif"] <- paste(Mmean-Fmean)
  mean.df[i, "ss_f"] <- paste(length(Mcuts$cuts))
  mean.df[i, "ss_m"] <- paste(length(Fcuts$cuts))
  mean.df[i, "ss_t"] <- paste(sum(length(Fcuts$cuts),length(Mcuts$cuts)))
  }
```

Here I run a linear model that is clearly trending in the direction I suspected, but is nonsignificant, likely because there are only 4 bins and thus 4 points.

```
lm1 <- lm(mean_dif ~ as.numeric(mean.df$bin), data=mean.df)
plot(mean.df$bin, mean.df$mean_dif)
abline(lm1)
summary(lm1)
```

[The photo attached shows the regression line of lm1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb5jF.png)

What is the appropriate way to assess significance here since the data are binned?
I have already run linear models on year:sex like so, but I am doing this to follow-up on the patterns.

Cross posted from https://www.biostars.org/p/446626/#446811
Question was not answered.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to not bin in the first place. Just represent the actual input years. That will remove the problem, and also preserve any information in the actual variation of years that is interesting.

If it is really necessary to bin the year data (though I don't see why it would be), do not pre-summarize the *trait* data before passing it to the model. The model is expecting to compute the trait means by year when you pass it the data, instead you are just giving it four data points, so it thinks you only have four measurements (one for each year I guess). However, within each of those points there is presumably lots of variation that you have removed with your loop over the four years averaging each year. Your dataset `mean.df` has removed basically all of the interesting information which existed in the original `Data` dataset.

How you can do this is by replacing each actual year in `Data` by the year of the bin that the observation belongs in.

You should get a plot that looks sort of like this (I simulated these data):

[image]

If you don't like how the plot looks, you can instead plot each year as a boxplot:

Ideally, you would have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> head(ideal_data)
Year trait Sex
1950 12 M
1910 10 F
1910 14 M
2000 15 F
2016 20 F
# or whatever

> boxplot(ideal_data$trait ~ ideal_data$Year)
```

[image]

As for the model, you can do something like this:

```
> model = lm(trait ~ Sex * Year, data = ideal_data)  # this gives the main and interaction effects
> summary(model)
# stuff about model here
```

That will preserve at least some of the interesting variation in the original dataset, and will still more or less work even with binned year data (as long as you make sure that the years are still numeric).